# React render based on mutable array

Tags: reactjs

The [React tutorial docs](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) say to avoid mutating data.

e.g.
Don't do mutable changes like this:

```
  handleClick(i){
    this.state.squares[i]='X';
  }
```

Use immutablility instead:

```
 handleClick(i) {
const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
squares[i] = 'X';
this.setState({squares: squares});
```

}

If I did go with the mutable version instead, is there a way to tell React to re-render the component somehow when the state changes?

Comment: This quite goes against how React works, but please look at `forceUpdate()` which should force a re-render, it is advised to not use it normally but if you have a use case where you need it this perhaps can help you.

Answer (score 0):

A link to a linkedIn article describing why documentation is important in software. [Link.](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/why-documentation-important-software-development-alexander-ryan)

> Good documentation can also help you learn from your mistakes, so you won't repeat them.

Someone has already asked this question, likely years ago, and there was a reason React implemented such a concise mechanism for setting a state object, instead of allowing it to be mutable. If you'd like to use a mutable object to keep state, do not use a `state` object, but instead use a reference.

The link below is the React documentation on a mutable, but consistent value you can reference in your React component.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref

Now the tricky bit is using it to cause a re-render. My solution will be to give the component you want to re-render a key that matches the reference's current value. Example

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.inputRef = React.createRef();  
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.inputRef.current += 1
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick} />;
        // Now with the `key` set as a ref value, the component will re-render
        // when the reference value changes
        <ChildComponentNeedingReRender key={this.inputRef.current} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I think more explanation would be appreciated for a comprehensive answer, but I hope this helps!